# how to access a variable from another nib file in ios

Tags: ios, ios5

I have two view controller files which is `InputViewController` and `CurrencyViewController`. I want to access the variable declared in `InputView` inside `CurrencyView`. It is designed in Empty Application Project.

Comment: The CurrencyViewController should have the instance of InputViewController. Then you can access that variable

Answer (score 2):

```
You can declare the variable globally in AppDelegate & then can access in both viewController.
The changes made in the variable will reflect in both controllers.
Make the variable as a property of AppDelegate.h class
eg. @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Var;
& synthesize it in AppDelegate.m
@synthesize Var;

declare "AppDelegate * appDelegate" in both Controllers.h & then in controller.m in viewDidLoad write  appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

now the variable can accessible using appDelegate.var anywhere in your code of both ViewController & changes are also reflected in both.
Hope this will work more efficiently for your need.
```

Comment: Thanks ! I already tried it. Still not working. Used protocols, object instance. no joy